# Can I have arithmetic operations in initialization?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Pot {
    public String shape;
    private int capacity;
    public ArrayList<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    public int free_space = capacity - flowers.size(); // why doesn't free_space work?

    public Pot(String shape, int capacity) {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        System.out.println(capacity); // test
        System.out.println(flowers.size()); // test
        System.out.println(free_space); //test
    }
    
    ....
}
```

Hi, why can't I get correct free_space? It's always 0. I found that `free_space = capacity - flowers.size()` doesn't work.

if we do like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pot p = new Pot("square", 8);
            Flower f = new Flower(....);
            .....
            Flower f6 = new Flower(....);
            p.insert(f);
            .....
            p.insert(f6);
}
```

It's supposed to be 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free_space` depends on two other parameters, when it is defined as `free_space = capacity - flowers.size()` it does not mean that it will be automatically recalculated.

However, this can be implemented with the help of getter which returns the result of calculation (no separate field is needed):

```java
public int getFreeSpace() {
    return capacity - flowers.size();
}
```

Also it's worth to override method `toString` to print the snapshot of `Pot` class and call this getter:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Pot: {shape=%s, capacity=%d, flowers count=%d, free size=%d}", 
        shape, capacity, flowers.size(), getFreeSpace());
}
```

Test:

```java
Pot p = new Pot("square", 8);
System.out.println(p); // Pot: {shape=square, capacity=8, flowers count=0, free size=8}

p.insert(new Flower());
System.out.println(p); // Pot: {shape=square, capacity=8, flowers count=1, free size=7}
// etc
```

However, starting from Java 8 where lambdas and functional interfaces were introduced, it is possible to replace the calculating getter with a field which in this case should be [`Supplier<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html):

```java
public Supplier<Integer> freeSpace = () -> capacity - flowers.size();
```

Then this supplier may be invoked as: `freeSpace.get()` and actual value is recalculated.

---

*Update after @dariosicily comment* Also, [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html) could be used with its method [`getAsInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html#getAsInt--):

```java
IntSupplier freeSpace = () -> capacity - flowers.size();

System.out.println(freeSpace.getAsInt());
```

Comment: Instead of `Supplier<Integer>` I think it is possible to use `IntSupplier` with `getAsInt` method.

Answer (score 0):

you do the calculation in the initialization. of course it will always return the 0 size